# AutoMapper - ignore destination members which source doesn't provide

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, automapper

I have Entities and Dtos that members doesn't exactly match. Entities have most of the time all members (for each column in the db), but Dtos have only those which are being send (needed) to the client.

So for example, when Dto comes from the client I want to transfer it to Entity and save changes in the database. This piece of code explains where I'm struggling right now:

```
public class ItemEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class ItemNameDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public void UpdateItem(ItemNameDto itemNameDto)
{
    using (var myc = ContextFactory.CreateMyContext())
    {
        var item = myc.Items.Where(i => i.Id == itemNameDto.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        // At this point I have the current Item from the database:
        // (while dubugging) item.Id=1
        // (while dubugging) item.Name="Item1"
        // (while dubugging) item.Category=1
        // (while dubugging) item.Foo=20
        // (while dubugging) item.Bar=40

        // Now I want to change only members, that appear in itemNameDto:
        // (while dubugging) itemDto.Id=1
        // (while dubugging) itemDto.Name="New name for Item1"

        item = Mapper.Map<Item>(itemDto);

        // (while dubugging) item.Id=1
        // (while dubugging) item.Name="New name for Item1"
        // (while dubugging) item.Category=1
        // (while dubugging) item.Foo=20
        // (while dubugging) item.Bar=40

        myc.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I would like to maintain all members, that don't appear in ItemNameDto. so I would like to have:

```
    item = Mapper.Map<Item>(itemDto);

    // (while dubugging) item.Id=1
    // (while dubugging) item.Name="New name for Item1"
    // (while dubugging) item.Category=1
    // (while dubugging) item.Foo=20
    // (while dubugging) item.Bar="This is bar"
```

Is there an easy way to do this automatically? Or do I have to create different mapping for all scenarios/all members?

Thanks,

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html?highlight=memberlist#selecting-members-to-validate

Comment: Use different `Map` method overload accepting existing target - `Mapper.Map(itemDto, item)`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu unfortunately this doesn't work. Destination members are null after mapping. I tried three options and it didn't work :/

Comment: That only applies to validation. About the mapping itself, @IvanStoev gave you the answer.

Comment: ah! right! thank you guys